# Markov chains - recurrence proof question involving probability generating functions

Tags: probability, markov-chains, generating-functions

I am working through the proof that $P_{ij}(s)=F_{ij}(s)P_{jj}(s)$ for $i \neq j $ where $P_{ij}(s)$ and $F_{ij}(s)$ are generating functions

I am stuck on this step

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} s^n
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n f_{ii}^{(k)} p_{ii}^{(n-k)}
s^n
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_{ii}^{(k)} s^k\sum_{n=k}^\infty   p_{ii}^{(n-k)}
s^{n-k}
$$

How is the final equality achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $n$ takes values from 1 to $\infty$ and k takes values from 1 to $n$. In other words, the effective range of values that k can take is 1 to $\infty$. Further, in $p_{ii}^{(n-k)}$, the number of steps $(n-k)\geq 0$, which means the minimum value that can be set for $n$ is $k$. Now, separate the terms that contain only $k$ and interchange the summations to get the final result.

Comment: Thank you very much - that was very helpful